# WCF Named Pipe Streaming

Tags: c#, wcf, stream, ipc, blocking

I have implemented a server/client test rig that uses streamed transfer mode with a net.pipe binding. This is all kind of working however I am hitting an issue when the actual server's stream implementation blocks on an empty buffer. Even if i remove all synchronization, set the concurrency mode to multiple I am having an issue where my client application is blocking on stream.Read.

So my client initiates a connection to the server with a "GetStream" call (on a non-UI thread), the actual stream implementation that's returned by the server is a blocking stream (say NetStream for example) so it will block when there are no bytes available to read. This is causing a complete lockup of the service host so now the client cannot make any further calls until the stream.read operation unblocks.

Can someone shed some light on this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved a working code for anonymous pipes, named pipes asynchronous and synchronous. From my experience I can tell that, you just cannot have shared memory buffer "empty". Even in Asynchronous, I believe, background threads are created to read and write synchronously.

So at the moment just consider this for a fact that,

the server must first send write to buffer => the client should read it => Client must write back to that buffer => Server must read it.

That cycle has to repeat forever for applications to not freeze. I am beginning to think this is what makes shared memory communication different via server/client socket. In shared memory approach you might not have to worry about synchronization also it dedicates client to a server such that client cannot exist with a server.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using the older 'async' style Begin/End Read/Write methods to allow asynchronously communication. Unfortunately there is no async/await support for named pipes in .net - however, you can wrap them using the `TaskFactory.FromAsync` methods.